# Jquery Url Split and grab mid value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL www.xyz.com/partyevent/zalen

Is there any way to grab the url mid value i.e "partyevent" and spit the parts before and after that. I want to get mid value "***partyevent***" for adding class into body.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
var url = window.location.pathname;
var count = url.match(new RegExp("/", 'g'));
var urlsplit = url.split("/");
var page_class = urlsplit[count.length];

alert(page_class);
    $('body').addClass(page_class);
});
```

thanks for help..

Comment: Why you need regex? Use `urlsplit[urlsplit.length - 2];` instead of `urlsplit[count.length]`

Comment: `urlsplit[1]` should be fine

Comment: @Satpal .. This is working U Rock ..\/,

Comment: `urlsplit[urlsplit.length - 2]` this is not correct for all conditions. what if it has ` `www.xyz.com/partyevent/zalen/somethingelse/more/some` check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$(function () { 
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var urlsplit = url.split("/"); // this returns array of ["","partyevent",zalen]
    var page_class = urlsplit[1]; // you need not bother about count when u need the word just after the domain

    alert(page_class);
    $('body').addClass(page_class);
});
```